# How to prevent a website to scroll to a particular section when the section slider auto-slides on mobile-view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, splidejs

I have 2 sliders, a story-list-carousel, and a story-view-carousel. When on mobile view, the screen starts auto-scrolling up to this section after the user passes this section and scrolls down towards the footer.

I have recorded the issue in a video preview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYXcrMBQEHA

As in the video, the top slide listCarousel and the bottom section where 3 images are shown, is the storyMainCarousel.

Slider JS code:

```
let storyMainCarousel = new Splide('#story-view-carousel', {
    type: 'fade',
    pagination: false,
    arrows: false,
    cover: true,
    autoplay: true,
    rewind: true,
}).mount();

let listCarousel = new Splide('#story-list-carousel', {
    direction: 'ttb',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    perPage: 8,
    perMove: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    rewind: true,
    isNavigation: true,
    gap: 18,
    pagination: false,
    arrows: false,
    cover: true,
    start: 0,
    dragMinThreshold: {
        mouse: 4,
        touch: 10,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        767: {
            direction: 'ltr',
            height: '4rem',
            perPage: 2.4,
            perMove: 1,
            gap: 10,
            autoplay: true,
            rewind: true,
            padding: { left: '0rem', right: '0rem' },
            start: 0,
            focus: 'center',
        },
    },

}).mount();
storyMainCarousel.sync(listCarousel);
```

HTML and SCSS code:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div id="story-list-carousel" class="splide mb-0">
        <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list">
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/mortarboard_cap.svg"
                        />
                        Education
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/basketball.svg"/>
                        Sports
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/briefcase.svg"/>
                        Business &amp; Finance
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/mortarboard_cap.svg"
                        />
                        Art &amp; Entertainment
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/basketball.svg"/>
                        News &amp; Politics
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/briefcase.svg"/>
                        Family &amp; Parenting
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/mortarboard_cap.svg"
                        />
                        Society &amp; Culture
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="tablinks">
                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/basketball.svg"/>
                        Regional &amp; Spiritual
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    <div id="story-view-carousel" class="splide tabcontent mb-0">
        <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list">
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="splide__slide">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img1.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img2.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="./assets/images/section5/img3.png"  />
                                    </figure>
                                    <figcaption class="about">
                                        <p class="para">
                                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                                        </p>
                                        <h3 class="m-0 title">
                                            Gillian Anderson
                                        </h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have come up with a temporary solution which is disabling the autoPlay functionality for both the sliders on mobile view and enabling the arrows for manual navigation for the listCarousel slider. I am still looking for a permanent solution and will really appreciate it if the community has a permanent solution for this issue... Thanks!